# react native android causes illegal number of arguments for update hotspot command when trying to focus component

Tags: android, react-native, focus, tvos

I am using react naive for tv application and some time i need to focus my component , but when trying to do it with TouchableOpacity ref and call method .focus() , i getting error

`illegal number of arguments for update hotspot command when trying to focus component`